# How to unmark header checkbox on dataGridView after refreshing the data c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

Header check box on selection select all the check boxes in the checkbox column. After selecting the header checkbox, when data refreshes, it is still displayed as marked on it.
I have the following code when clicking on Ok button, it loads data in the datagridview with header check box and all the check boxes in each rows. Now, select the header checkbox that selects all the check boxes in all the rows. Then, again clicking on Ok button, it reloads the data but the check mark on the header check box is still displaying instead of not checked.

```
        private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadDataGridView();

        CheckBox ckBoxHeader = new CheckBox();

        //Get the column header cell bounds
        Rectangle rect = datagridview1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true);
        rect.Y = 3;

        //align header check box in the middle center at rect.X = 82
        rect.X = (rect.Location.X + (rect.Width / 2)) - 10 ;

        ckBoxHeader.Size = new Size(18, 18);
        //Change the location of the CheckBox to make it stay on the header
        ckBoxHeader.Location = rect.Location;
        datagridview1.Columns[0].Frozen = true;

        ckBoxHeader.CheckedChanged += ckBoxHeader_CheckedChanged;

        //Add the CheckBox into the DataGridView
        datagridview1.Controls.Add(ckBoxHeader);
    }


   private void ckBoxHeader_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= datagridview1.RowCount - 1; j++)
        {
            datagridview1[0, j].Value = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
        }
        datagridview1.EndEdit();

    }
```

Comment: Without any code to show what you've tried so far, it would be impossible to help you. We cannot write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: Speak with code.

Comment: Added code, now if you have any hints to the above @Keyur Patel and @ M Adeel Khalid of if anyone. Thank you!

Comment: Could you try the simple way first: add a line `ckBoxHeader.IsChecked = false;` after `ckBoxHeader.CheckedChanged += ckBoxHeader_CheckedChanged;`.

Comment: You say that in ok button click you reload the data but i do not see that method's code. Anyhow, in the `buttonOk_Click` you add a checkbox to the grid. If the checkbox is clicked, it will stay clicked. You need to get that checkbox after you have reloaded the data and set it back to false.

Comment: In `buttonOk_Click`, the only code you need is `LoadDataGridView`. The rest of the code doesnt need to be executed everytime the button is clicked. Study the code you have there and you will arrive at the same conclusion. You do not need to set the column to frozen everytime and the other stuff. Tge only thing that changes is your data and the header checkbox's state

Comment: @CodingYoshi, thank you.  The issue has been solved by moving the addHeaderCheckBox and other code to the load event of the form and the event code inside the LoadDataGridView method. In addition, adding the code headerCheckBox.checked = false. Before, adding this code, it was not changing the check boxed click status. And below is my code that resolved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solved my issue of unselecting the header check box. The above code should be rewritten as follows in order to headerCheckBox.Checked = false; to be working:
Load Event Code -

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addHeaderCheckBox();
        changeDataGridViewColumnReadonly();
        datagridview1.Columns[0].Frozen = true;            
    }
```

Load datagridview method code -

```
        private void LoadDataGridView()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string WhereClause = " WHERE NO LIKE '" + textBoxNumber.Text.ToString().Substring(0,12) + "%' AND (DATE_TIME_START BETWEEN " + General.BuildOraDateString(dateTimePickerStart.Value) + " AND " + General.BuildOraDateString(dateTimePickerEnd.Value) + ") AND STATUS_IND = 'ST' ";

        dt = Unit.GetData(WhereClause);
        this.datagridview1.Refresh();
        this.datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

        headerCheckBox.Checked = false;

        headerCheckBox.MouseClick += new 
        MouseEventHandler(headerCheckBox_MouseClick);

        datagridview1.CellValueChanged +=
      new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(datagridview1_CellValueChanged);

        datagridview1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged +=
          new EventHandler(datagridview1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged);

        datagridview1.CellPainting +=
          new 
      DataGridViewCellPaintingEventHandler(datagridview1_CellPainting);
    }
```

Ok button click event-

```
     private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadDataGridView();
        totalCheckBoxes = dgvBaleDisposition.RowCount;

    }
```